# Soundclips pollute my memory (JAVA 9)

Tags: java, audio, javasound

as off JAVA9 I had to rewrite my code to play a sound in JAVA to this.
The core was copied from an other source found on this forum.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;

    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
    import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
    import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
    import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

    /**
     * Main class.
     */
    public class Sound
    {
        /**
         * Main.
         * @param commandLine
         * @throws MalformedURLException 
         * @throws InterruptedException 
         */
        public static void main(String[] commandLine) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
        {
            URL u;
            PlaySound ps;

            for(String path : commandLine) // Play all the sounds (*.wav)
            {
                System.out.println(path);
                u = Paths.get(path).toUri().toURL();
                ps = new PlaySound(u);
                ps.start();        
                ps.join(); // Wait till the tread is gone.
            }

            for(Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) // Collect the list of Threads pending.
            {
                System.out.println("[" + t.getName() + "]"); // Observe the "Direct Clip" threads.
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Asynchronous sound player.
     */
    class PlaySound extends Thread
    {
        /**
         * Stream for this sound.
         */
        private AudioInputStream a;

        /**
         * Duration of the sound.
         */
        private long time;

        /**
         * URL of the sound clip.
         */
        private URL u;

        /**
         * Clip object for this sound
         */
        private Clip clip;

        /**
         * Constructor.
         * @param sound URL of sound to play.
         */
        public PlaySound(URL sound)
        {
            u = sound;
        }

        /** (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
         */
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            setName("PlaySound");
            try
            {
                a = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(u);
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                clip.open(a);
                time = clip.getMicrosecondLength();
                clip.start();
                Thread.sleep(time / 1000 + 1000);
                clip.stop();
            }
            catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException | InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.err.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

It works, I guess the code could be better than this, BUT I found that thread instances remain in memory. How can I get rid of these.
You will see that the Thread, named PlaySound, disappears. The culprit is "Direct Clip".
;JOOP!

Comment: Once the `run` method returns and nothing else holds a reference to the `Thread` it is eligible for GC. Are you certain that those two conditions are met?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not just a snippet.

Comment: @Boris the Spider: the Thread that remains is NOT that of the shown code but a Thread called "Direct Clip". See the info above. ;JOOP!

Comment: @hendrik: I replaced the source by a reduced sample that should be runnable, except for the call to 'error()'. ;JOOP!

Comment: *"I replaced the source by a reduced sample that should be runnable"* If you read the MCVE document linked by @hendrik, you apparently did not understand it. An MCVE should be ready to run (including a `main(..)` method) as copy/pasted without any changes at all. It should even include imports.

Comment: @*: I'm sorry, I had overlooked that it was a link. I managed to create a runnable program with minimal decorations. When you run it with multiple *.wav arguments you'll see that every sound caused a sticky thread beyond your control.;JOOP! P.S. I already tried to use a single instance of "Clip", but it seems not reusable.

Comment: Fyi: "Joop" is my real name.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you make the audio stream and the clip members of the `PlaySound` class? That makes garbage collection so much harder (and later), because it can only happen when the `PlaySound` instance is collected, not right after the `run()` method has finished. Have you tried to declare both clip and stream as local variable instead?

Comment: @Hendrik: originally the Thread 'hangs' under a library class that loads and activates a collection of sounds. I will consider that after the "Direct Clip" goes away. Btw.: the latter is there still after hours, as the calling application is almost permanently active.

Comment: It is usually bad form to open and run a Clip at the same time. If you are going to do that, should use a SourceDataLine instead, as it will run more quickly and efficiently. I don't understand why you are including a "close" method. The clip should just play out. I could better help with providing an improved container for these playbacks if I understood the goal of the program. Am reluctant to spin out arbitrary possibilities. What did you have to change to make it work in Java9? What were you doing before?

Comment: Many questions at once. First: I used Applet.newAudioClip(url).play(); for years, but that is deprecated since 9. Second: I got the new code from another post in this forum. Third: the purpose of my application is to play warning sounds now and then. Forth: obviously I need correct code as mine is not good. And I can't find the right usage at Oracle either.

Comment: @all: obviously meeting some objections did not lead to any solution at all. I give up.

Comment: @all: I found a reasonable solution at:  http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-play-back-audio-in-java-with-examples